# Fancybox2 with json imagegroup does not show the next image

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I want to update my gallery to the fancybox 2. Before everything worked in version 1.3.4
Now it is not possible to show the next image in the slideshow. It is always displayed first.
However, if I go back previous and next then everything works.

Look here: http://f.cl.ly/items/3Z1W0t2Z0U1U39452Z1a/fancybox_error.m4v

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var images = [];
        $.getJSON("/json/235", function(data) {
            images = data.items;
        }).error(function(e) { console.log( e ); });

        $(".fancybox").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.fancybox(images, {
                "zoomSpeedIn":0,
                "zoomSpeedOut":0,
                "padding":10,
                "overlayShow":true,
                "nextEffect":"none",
                "nextClick":true,
                "helpers":{
                    "overlay":{
                        "opacity":0.5,
                        "css": { "background-color":"#000" }
                    },
                    "thumbs":{ "width":50, "height":50 }
                },
                index : $(this).attr("rel"),
                prevEffect : "slideOut",
                nextEffect : "slideIn",
                nextClick : true,
                type: "image" 
            });
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

the json file looks like

```
{"items":[{
    "href":"\/images\/get\/resize\/1200\/1200\/gallery\/2010-12-12_Fraport_Werft\/SES_6880_01.JPG",
    "title":"Fraport Werft"}, {
    "href":"\/images\/get\/resize\/1200\/1200\/gallery\/2010-12-12_Fraport_Werft\/SES_6888_01.JPG",
    "title":"Fraport Werft"}
]}
```

Comment: what is this option for? `index : $(this).attr("rel"),` because `index` is used to set the starting element of the gallery and in this case is equal to the `rel` attribute of the clicked element.... have you tried removing it?

Comment: In the attribute rel is a number from 0 to x. If I remove this, the pictures always start at position 0

Comment: could you show a link with the issue?

Comment: I saw the link, thanks. What is the reason to use JSON when you can get the images of the gallery from the `href` itself? Bear in mind that the `rel` attribute is used by fancybox to determine what elements belong to the same gallery. At the end, if you remove the JSON script and simply use `$(".fancybox").fancybox();` (besides to setting the same `rel` attribute to the `<a>` tags) it will work flawlessly.

Comment: I think this is more a design issue ;)

Comment: I know it goes without json. But with json it is possible to show a slide show without changing the page. What the user want ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in one of my comments, you should bear in mind that the `rel` attribute is used by fancybox to determine what elements belong to the same gallery. It seems that the fact you are using the `rel` attribute to get the `index` via `index : $(this).attr("rel"),` confuses fancybox to get the right order of the gallery.

If you are willing to updated/upgrade your gallery to fancybox v2.x you may also consider to upgrade your `DOCTYPE` to HTML5, in this way you could use the `data-*` attribute to set the right `index` of your gallery elements (and leave alone the `rel` attribute)

So in [your example](http://www.pitlanepics.de/galerie/-/-/show/174/MINI_Challenge/seite1/) for instance, change this :

```
<a rel="0" class="fancybox" .....
```

to this :

```
<a data-index="0" class="fancybox" .....
```

and so on and so forth. Then in your script, change this line :

```
index : $(this).attr('rel'),
```

to this

```
index: $(this).data("index"),
```

... and that pretty much will solve the issue.

[SEE DEMO HERE](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/jsonImagesIndexIssue_27jul12.html)